# Como fazer upload de foto usando o jQuery PictureCut?

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

Gostaria de fazer *upload* de foto utilizando o exemplo do [jQuery PictureCut](http://picturecut.tuyoshi.com.br/).

Segui todas as orientações fornecidas pelo site instalando as pastas e setando elas ao código, porém não está funcionando no meu servidor. Ela nem envia e nem aparece aquela janela de confirmação que aparece no modelo do site.

Veja meu código abaixo.

```html
<html>
<head>

<!-- Última versão CSS compilada e minificada -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Tema opcional -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Última versão JavaScript compilada e minificada -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>        

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.picture.cut/src/jquery.picture.cut.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container_image">
</div><script>
$("#container_image").PictureCut({
                  InputOfImageDirectory       : "image",
                  PluginFolderOnServer        : "/jquery.picture.cut/",
                  FolderOnServer              : "/uploads/",
                  EnableCrop                  : true,
                  CropWindowStyle             : "Bootstrap"
              });

              </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual o erro que está gerando para você? Gerar algum erro no console?

Comment: vi que você está utilizando 2 temas (bootstrap e jQuery-UI) vc fez isso propositalmente?

Comment: Tudo que eu utilizei foi seguindo as instruções do link http://picturecut.tuyoshi.com.br/

Comment: Acontece algum erro? Verifica o console do seu navegador, acredito que possa ser problema de incompatibilidade entre os scripts que você está usando

Comment: O link do plugin não abriu aqui. :(, não sei como funciona para poder te ajudar.

Answer (score -1):

Esse cdn do jqueryCut aparentemente esta fora do ar , ao menos eu não consegui visualizar.
Confirme se esse cdn esta online ou você pode baixar os arquivos diretamente do git

Click [aqui](https://github.com/tuyoshivinicius/jQuery-Picture-Cut")